# Reverse from POST method in django class based view (DetailView)

Tags: django, redirect

I have probably trivial question but I am newbie in Django and I don't know why I get error when I want to redirect here. I get proper url but I get error *'str' object has no attribute 'get'*. What do I wrong? Form is correct and object is created in db. It's only about wrong redirect. Thanks for help.

*My urls.py:*

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='blog-home'),
    path('user/<str:username>/', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-posts'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
    path('comments/delete/<int:pk>/', views.CommentDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete-comment'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='blog-about'),
```

]

*views.py*

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comments'] = Comment.objects.all()[::-1]
        context['comm_form'] = CommentCreateForm()
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST':  
            comm_form = CommentCreateForm(request.POST)
            comm_form.instance.post = Post.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
            comm_form.instance.author = self.request.user 
            comm_form.save()
            return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs.get('pk')})
        else:
            comm_form = CommentCreateForm()
            return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs.get('pk')})
```

*models.py*

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class Comment(models.Model):
    comm_content = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    add_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Comment of post {self.post} posted at {self.add_date}."

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.post.pk})
```

[Error view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnEhJ.png)

Comment: Your view returns a string, not a `HttpResponse`. But you will need to show the details of your `PostDetailView` such that we can help you.

Comment: Of course, sorry, I forgot add the most important :) Already edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`reverse(..)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.reverse) returns a *string* that contains the path to which you redirect. But a view needs to return a `HttpResponse`, for example a [**`HttpResponseRedirect`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect).

You can make use of the [**`redirect(..)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) to combine calculating the reverse, and wrapping the result in a `HttpResponse`. So you can modify your code to:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comments'] = Comment.objects.all()[::-1]
        context['comm_form'] = CommentCreateForm()
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST':  
            comm_form = CommentCreateForm(request.POST)
            comm_form.instance.post = Post.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
            comm_form.instance.author = self.request.user 
            comm_form.save()
            return redirect('post-detail', pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        else:
            return redirect('post-detail', pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
```